# Get Cell Format from Google Sheet API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'd like to retrieve the format/type of the cell that set in google sheet, for example Plain text, Number, Date, Time and etc from the Google Sheet API.
[Google Sheet format screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQUeP.png)
[Google Sheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbi3Q.png)

I'm using the API from this [Srijan's reference](https://www.srijan.net/blog/integrating-google-sheets-with-php-is-this-easy-know-how), it only able to pull out the values of the cells, but I need the format as well.

The code reference as below:

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $getRange);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

Output as below:

```
{
header 1: "A1", - text
header 2: "100", - number
header 3: "888.88", - currency
header 4: "10 Apr 2020", - date
header 5: "E1", - text
header 6: "F1", - text
header 7: "G1", - text
header 8: "H1", - text
header 9: "I1", - text
header 10: "J1", - text
header 11: "K1", - text
header 12: "L1", - text
header 13: "M1" - text
},
```

Desired Output:

```
{
header 1: {
    "value" : "A1",
    "type" : "text"
},
header 2: {
    "value" : "100",
    "type" : "number"
}
},
```

According to the [Google Sheet API reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells), it seems we can actually get the format of the cells. But how can we integrate with the API I used above?

Comment: What is `etc` of `Plaint text, Number, Date, Time, etc`?

Comment: @Tanaike Etcetera or others. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the values, you want to retrieve, except for `Plaint text, Number, Date, Time`?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry, let me get your question right. are you asking what kind of values i'd like to retrieve?

Comment: @Tanaike i updated the sample code above. the values of the gsheet would be something like this. regardless what values, I'd like to get the format of the cell set in the gsheet, for example Plain Text, Number, Date or Time.

Comment: @Tanaike currently i only can get the values of the cell, but don't have format.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can understand that you want to retrieve the type of value in a cell. But I couldn't understand about the types except for `Plain Text, Number, Date or Time`. For example, the boolean type, the background color, font size, font name and so on are included?

Comment: @Tanaike i've added a screenshot in the question. kindly take a look. not the bg color, font size but the type of the cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: At first, I had asked the values, you want to retrieve, except for `Plaint text, Number, Date, Time` in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112242/get-cell-format-from-google-sheet-api#comment116886302_66112242). From this, you added [a sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQUeP.png). From this sample, I proposed an answer for retrieving the format values.

Comment: But from your replying of `thank you. i relooked and corrected on my end and it did return as per your expected result. but do I have to specify the getNumberFormat? because I would have different type of cells in a gsheet.`, I understood that you want to retrieve other values. From this, I understood that in this case, my answer is not useful for your situation. So I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your actual goal, can you update your question by adding the sample output values you expect? By this, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike sorry for the misunderstanding. my goal is to get the type of the cell that set in the google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. From `my goal is to get the type of the cell that set in the google sheet.` and your added sample output value, it seems that it is different from [your sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQUeP.png). So I'm confusing about your goal. I apologize for this. When your added sample JSON data is correct, you want to check whether a cell value is number or string. Is my understanding correct? If it's so, how will you do the date and time? You want to return them as number? And, what is `header 1` of `header 1:`?

Comment: @Tanaike 'you want to check whether a cell value is number or string' - correct. if date, then date. i just giving few examples only. 'header 1' is the first row of the sheet and i took it as header. the screenshot in the question was to show where to set the format of the cell in gsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. I think that it can achieve to check whether the cell value is number or string. But I cannot understand about your `Desired Output:`. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you provide sample input and output you expect using a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for trying to understand and help. I've added another screenshot. the first screenshot is to show the list of format. the 2nd screenshot is to show the cell values after being set with format.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I understood that you want to retrieve not only the cell value type as number and string, but also date. In your goal, you want to check these 3 types of number, string and date. How about other types? After I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike it should be as dynamic as possible, depends on the sheet, not limited to only date, numbers, and plain text. retrieve whatever the format from the cells.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. Although I tried to understand about your expected values from `it should be as dynamic as possible, depends on the sheet, not limited to only date, numbers, and plain text. retrieve whatever the format from the cells.`, unfortunately I cannot still understand about your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. So can you give me a time to do? When I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get [data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells) about specific cells, you need to call the method [get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) of `spreadsheets`. You can `Try this API`, setting `includeGridData` to `true` and explore the result to check if there is the information that you are looking for. Once you find it, let's get it with php.

### How to get cell data in php (including cell format)

1. Follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) guide to php and check that you get the desired result
2. Call the method `get` of a `spreadsheet` including the parameter `includeGridData`
3. Call the method `getSheets` of `spreadsheets` and store the result
4. Search your desired data in your result

```
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = 'your spreadsheet id';
$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId,['includeGridData' => true]);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheets();
$formats = $sheet[0]['data'][0]['rowData'][0]['values'];
```

### Considerations

- The last zero indicates the row number, if you have header you can set it to `1`
- `formats` is an array that includes all the columns of a given row.
- Access to the first column and display its value with:

  ```
  $myJson = json_encode($formats[0]);
  echo $myJson;
  ```
- There is an object (`effectiveValue`) that indicates if the value is `boolValue`, `formulaValue`, `numberValue` or `stringValue`. However, `dates` are considered `numberValue`. To differentiate between types of `numberValue` there is another object (`effectiveFormat`) that displays [cellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#cellformat). It has one property called `numberFormat` that indicates the kind of `numberValue` that is in the cell.

With this information you should be able to achieve your goal.

### Work around

Use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and [getnumberformats](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformats) instead of php.

Comment: a quick ques: how can i select with tab as well? :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: lets say 1 sheet has 5 tabs. can I still get the format of the cells from the 2nd tab? tabs can be found at the bottom part of the sheet.

Comment: I think that you are misleading concepts. 1 spreadsheet has 5 sheets and you can access throw the tabs. If you want to access to the another sheet, you have to change this number: `$formats = $sheet[$sheetNumber]['data'][0]['rowData'][0]['values'];`. Keep in mid that the index start with zero.

Comment: oh great! didnt see that $sheetNumber index. that's what I want. once again, thank you fullfine!